# Create cv::Mat header for const data

Tags: c++, opencv

Typically if my data is non-const, I can initialize a cv::Mat header on top of it for algebraic manipulation.

```
float awesome_data[24] = {0};
cv::Mat awesome_mat = cv::Mat(6, 4, CV_32F, awesome_data);
```

But, if my data is const

```
const float awesome_data[24] = {0};
cv::Mat awesome_mat = cv::Mat(6, 4, CV_32F, awesome_data);
```

will have an error: `unable to convert from const void * to void *`. I know that I won't be changing awesome_mat, what is the best way to do this?

Currently, I have to do a const cast

```
const float awesome_data[24] = {0};
cv::Mat awesome_mat = cv::Mat(6, 4, CV_32F, const_cast<float *>(awesome_data));
```

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: If an object is cv::Mat, I can perform any linear algebraic, image processing, ... operations. What can I not do with it? :-)

Comment: I don't mean that. const_cast works - is there something else that you want or expect?

Comment: I was hoping that there is a better way to do this than using const_cast. Perhaps someone knows if OpenCV has a cv::const_Mat equivalent.

Comment: sorry but for me your question sounds like 'is there any way to add 2 values without using +'.

Comment: @fazo: Not at all. const_cast is semantically wrong. By casting constness away, you remove the protection layer that prevents you from accidently changing the data.

Comment: @DatChu: Did you try what happens if you do 'cv::Mat const mat(6,4,CV_32F, awesome_data)? (the cv::Mat foo = cv::Mat(...) is useless, you can just do cv::Mat foo(...)).

Comment: There just is no cv::Mat constructor that lets you pass a const pointer, so no, this is not possible.  Neither is there a special const_Mat...

Answer (score 9):

The data in `cv::Mat` can always be modified. To be more safe you should copy the data:

```
const float awesome_data[24] = {0};
cv::Mat awesome_mat = cv::Mat(6, 4, CV_32F, const_cast<float *>(awesome_data)).clone();
```

With `const cv::Mat` only the matrix header is readonly but not the data ([Differences of using "const cv::Mat &", "cv::Mat &", "cv::Mat" or "const cv::Mat" as function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468537/differences-of-using-const-cvmat-cvmat-cvmat-or-const-cvmat)):

```
const cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::zeros(6, 4, CV_32F);
mat += 1; // compiles and runs fine!
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this completely safely is to make a copy of `awesome_data` (one way or another). The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32436681/2550133) by @R1tschY makes a copy of the data using an OpenCV method, which itself requires a `const_cast`. To avoid the `const_cast` altogether, the memory should be copied outside of OpenCV (since OpenCV does not respect const data). This would be one way:

```cpp
const float awesome_data[24] = {0};
cv::Mat awesome_mat = cv::Mat(6, 4, CV_32F); //Allocates its own memory
memcpy(awesome_mat.data, awesome_data, 24*sizeof(float)); //Copy into the allocated memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, OpenCV does not have a const_Mat class. However, by using

```
const float awesome_data[24] = {0};
const cv::Mat awesome_mat = cv::Mat(6, 4, CV_32F, const_cast<float *>(awesome_data));
```

you preserve constness.

Comment: Your post seems not to be in agreement with the @R1tschY 's one (and with my experience). Could you comment on what kind of 'constness' you mean, not to confuse anyone?

Comment: I think this would be bad advice. With this solution, the very next line might modify awsome_data itself. This is not const data in any meaningful sense.