# Mat& vs Mat opencv 2 c++

Tags: c++, opencv

well I’m a little confused about passing Mat to function and retrieving it
so what is the difference between let's say

```
 void GetFrame(Mat& frame)
          Vs 
 void GetFrame(Mat frame) 
          Vs 
 Mat GetFrame()
```

Update:

in which version the changes to frame inside the function  body will result in change in the original frame passed to function

Comment: `void GetFrame(Mat& frame)` takes a reference to a `Mat` and doesn't return anything. `void GetFrame(Mat frame)` takes a copy of `Mat` and doesn't return anything. `Mat GetFrame()` takes nothing and returns a `Mat`.

Comment: Important to mention that in the second version the Pixeldata isn copied, only the Header is copied!!

Comment: in which version the changes to frame inside the function body will result in change in the original frame passed to function

Comment: and which is more memory effective

Comment: Eslam Ahmed, you should pick up a basic C++ tutorial concerning your initial questions, as those very basic things are explained there. Concerning your question about "more memory effective", just check the OpenCV sources and that should become clear, too.

Comment: @Ahmed: if the image data passed to the function is reallocated within the function (e.g. resize) without manipulating pixels before reallocation then only the first function will change the original frame. If only popixel values are manipulated but no new memory is allocated to the Mat within the function tthen first and second functions modify original image. Third function will modify original image iff it doesnt reallocate Mat data memory in each call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences of using "const cv::Mat &", "cv::Mat &", "cv::Mat" or "const cv::Mat" as function parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468537/differences-of-using-const-cvmat-cvmat-cvmat-or-const-cvmat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit of care, you can get all 3 versions to work and do the same thing, but I will try to explain the details.

First, a `Mat` object is really just a small header which contains metadata about the real data, (eg, number of rows and columns), and a pointer to the actual data. In most cases, the pointer is actually a smart pointer, with reference counting, and can be shared by multiple `Mat` objects, and automatically deleted when the last remaining `Mat` object stops pointing to it. *(`Mat` objects can also point to data it doesn't own, ie if you have some data you got from a different library/API, and want to reuse the same memory rather than copy it.)*

#### 1. Pass by reference version

Version 1 of your function is perhaps the simplest. The caller's `Mat` object is copied *by reference*, which obviously means that any modifications to the `Mat` object's metadata (including the (smart) pointer) will be visible to the caller upon return. The underlying data will obviously reflect any modification made by the function.

#### 2. Pass by value version

In version 2 of your function (passing in a `Mat` object by value), the small header represented by `Mat` is copied and passed to the function. The copy is shallow: metadata and the (smart) pointer is copied, but the underlying data is shared by the caller's `Mat` object and the callee's `Mat` object. The part that you have to be careful is that if the function modifies the metadata of the copied `frame` object, *these changes will not be visible to the caller*.

So for example, if you pass an empty `Mat`, you may be surprised with the result: First, the meta-data of the empty `Mat` is copied. When the function calls something like `frame.create(newRows, newCols, newType);`, the `create` function will allocate a new chunk of memory since `frame.rows != newRows`, `frame.cols != newCols`, and `frame.type() != newType`, and the (callee's copy alone of) `frame` metadata is updated reflect the newly allocated data. When the function returns, its `frame` object will hold the only reference to the smart pointer, so the data will be automatically discarded. The caller will still have just an empty header.

If, however, the `Mat` object that is passed in to the function already has the correct dimensions and type, `frame.create()` will do nothing, which means that any modification made by the callee to the underlying data will be visible to the caller.

#### 3. Return by value version

The 3rd version is similar to the second, except that rather than making a copy of the meta-data when the function is called, the function instead allocates a `Mat` however it sees fit, and the meta-data (including pointer to the underlying data) is copied back to the caller upon return. The underlying data survives and is accessible to the caller.

### Summary

If you don't know the size and type of the data ahead of time, you cannot use pass-by-value. If you do know the size/type, you can use pass-by-value, and the pre-allocated memory will be used.

Pass-by-reference will use the pre-allocated memory if possible, or allocate new memory, and in either case the caller will always see the new header/data.

Return-by-value also will always work properly, but it does have to re-allocate new memory every call, which may be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

"2. Pass by value version" is INCORRECT, at least for the below example which drove me nuts, but I managed to fix using .clone()

```
Mat image = imread("anyimage.jpg");
Rect rect(Point(40, 50), Point(60,80) ); // assuming size is over 80
if(!image.empty())
{
imshow("original image",image);
waitKey(0);

test_if_it_adds_a_rect(image, rect);
imshow("returned image",image);
waitKey(0);
}
```

//and here is the function

```
void test_if_it_adds_a_rect(Mat image, Rect rect)
{
 rectangle(image, rect, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 2); 
}
```

//even this one

```
void test_if_it_adds_a_rect(Mat image1, Rect rect1)
{
rectangle(image1, rect1, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 2); 
}
```

You will notice that the returned image has changed and has a blue rect.
BUT to solve this you need to use image.clone() inside the function instead of image

Comment: in the pass by vlaue version : the small header represented by Mat is copied and passed to the function but the actual data is not copied so any change in the data itself will be reflected to the image so it is not incorrect