# A parameter with const cv::Mat type will changed in function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some problem with cv::Mat object. Output of the below code was wrong

```
void processFrame(const cv::Mat image, MyTracker& t)
{
    //some code
}

void main()
{
    MyTracker t;
    cv::VideoCapture(0);
    cv::Mat im , im_gray;
    while (true)
    {
         cap >> im; 
         cv::cvtColor(im, im_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
         processFrame(im_gray,t);
         cv::Rect r = t.bb_rot.boundingRect(); // get last bounding box of tracker 
         std::cout<<r.x<<"\t"<<r.y<<"\t"<<r.width<<"\t<<r.height;
    }
}
```

But when i use `processFrame(im_gray.clone(),t);` instead, solved the problem and result is correct.
What is the problem that `clone()` function can solved this , however the first parameter of `processFrame` is `const cv::Mat image` and can't change in `ProcessFrame`.

I think `image` object will change in `processFrame` function

Comment: the Mat header is const but not the pixel data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences of using "const cv::Mat &", "cv::Mat &", "cv::Mat" or "const cv::Mat" as function parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468537/differences-of-using-const-cvmat-cvmat-cvmat-or-const-cvmat)

Answer (score 0):

`cv::Mat` is a like a smart pointer. When you run the following code:

```
cv::Mat a = cv::Mat(...);
cv::Mat b = a;
```

You have two objects: `a` and `b` which points to the same `data`. The last one gets destructed will also free the memory.
So in your case, you are not changing any of the values of the `const` matrix you get, you are changing the data, which is shared by all of them.
When you use `clone()` method, you actually allocate a new data buffer and copy the data to it.

I hope it answers your question, you can read more here: [cv::Mat docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automaticallocation)

Comment: Tanks. But i don't understand why a const object will changed in function?

Comment: The object itself is just metadata and a pointer to a buffer (the image data). The const means you can't change the metadata (size, type, etc.) but the data itself can get changed.